# cannot remove /n and /n/n from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file containing some string like below:
[image]

Now, I want to get rid of all `/n`, and `/n/n`. Here is the code that I have written, but it does not work! Can some one please tell me what is wrong with this code? Also, I want to keep real new lines, because later I want to be able to read each line and process something on it.

```
lin=read_file.read()
print(line.strip().strip("").strip('\n').strip('\t').replace(r"\n\n","_").replace('\r\n', ' '));
```

Comment: Before even getting to your main problem, forward slashes and backslashes are different characters. If someone shows you how to remove `/n`, as you're asking for, that's not going to have any effect at all—or, worse, you might have some string like `analgesic/nsaid` that you'll turn into `analgesicsaid`.

Comment: @AGN Gazer thanks for the comment; then, what 's the solution in these situations?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your file, i.e., using GoogleDrive, OneDrive, etc. assuming it does not contain private information. If it does - clean it up before sharing.

Comment: You also say: _"I want to keep real new lines, because later I want to be able to read each line and process something on it."_ How are we supposed to know when a new line is "real" and when it is not "real"?

Comment: @AGNGazer, I want to remove characters like /n/n from the string but the real new line, I assume I do not see them!

Comment: Alright, I have to tell you I think @TwiN is right. However, I think you may want a different replacement.

Comment: @AGNGazer, thanks for letting me take your time! I have already used .replace('\\n', '|||') but this does not work, either. What  do you mean by different replacement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TwiN solution is basically correct. I think that most likely you will want to replace `\\n` with `\n`. Then the text will appear properly formatted.

The solution is to do something similar to @TwiN but replace `'\\n'` with a "real" newline `'\n'`:

```
line.replace('\\n', '\n')
```

Now, possibly another problem that you are encountering is that you are not saving the changes to the file. To do that you need to open the file in the `'r+'` mode:

> **WARNING:** This will change your file!!! MAKE A COPY BEFORE RUNNING THIS CODE!

```
with open('clinicaltrials_051817_Not_Null.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    new_lines = [line.replace('\\n', '\n') for line in lines]
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(new_lines)
    f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\`.

e.g.

```
.replace('\\n', ' ')
```

If you try to replace `\n`, it will try to replace a new line, however, by escaping the `\`, it will try to replace the string `\n`.

Comment: It’s not clear if \n in the OP is literal or a representation of newlines. I’m leaning towards the latter

Comment: @jwm Look at the picture -- it shows `\n\n` instead of an actual new line

Comment: True, if the picture is the literal contents of the file and not a subset of `repr(lin)`

Comment: @TwiN thanks for the comment, I used  .replace('\\n\\n','_')) and .replace('\\n',' ')  but it is still not working, is there any other solution?